# Cast and production of “Air Devils” (1932)

Tags: production, casting, air-devils

I am looking for information about the cast and production of 1932 American film *Air Devils*.

It's mentioned in Stephen Pendo's *Aviation in the Cinema* (Scarecrow Press, 1985) on pages 12-13:

> The cheaply-made AIR DEVILS (1932) told of two friendly aviators who formerly fought against each other during the war and now fly mock air duels for a carnival. When the German tries to rob the kid brother (who is flying a payroll) of the American, the American intervenes and both aviators are killed.

Neither Wikipedia nor IMDb seem to have articles on it. My searches always lead to different movies, 1932 [*Sky Devils*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Devils) with Spencer Tracy or 1938 [*Air Devils*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Devils) (or to Don Dwiggins's book about stunt flying).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know, I followed that debate. However, this is not an identification question. I am looking for more information about a specific film, mentioned in a book. Is there a way I could phrase my question to make this clearer?

Comment: I added Pendo's summary again, because it is clear it's not an identification question with the title apparently known. Without the excerpt from the book, it may puzzle future readers that my answer is supposed to be correct, when it contains information about a movie with a different title and release year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [*Air Eagles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021591/) (USA, 1931), starring [Lloyd Hughes](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0400763/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) as Bill Ramsey, [Norman Kerry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0449908/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) as Otto Schumann and [Shirley Grey](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0336956/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) as Eve. It was directed by [Phil Whitman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0926171/?ref_=tt_ov_dr), produced by [Larry Darmour Productions](https://www.imdb.com/search/title?companies=co0130983) and released on December 20, 1931. Written by [Hampton Del Ruth](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0215874/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr1), it was suggested by [E. V. Durling](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0244219/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr2) and [Lewis R. Foster](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0287931/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr3), with uncredited additional writer [Walter Q. MacDonald](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3788850/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr4).

From a 2015 [review](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021591/reviews?ref_=tt_urv) by kidboots:

> It begins at a flea bitten carnival with the old "two guys in love with the same girl" refrain. The lucky one who has his affection returned is Otto (Norman Kerry) but it is clear he is a "no good nik"!! [...] It all comes out when the carnival plays Bill's home town, the three of them decide to stay and Bill finds there are jobs a plenty flying planes for the mines but when Otto sits for the test he realises his past won't bear close inspection. He then persuades Eve to "vamp" Bill's kid brother, Eddie, who has a huge crush on her and is all set to take a job in the mail flying corps. She wants him to take the dangerous mining job - Otto intends Eddie to land in a remote spot, then claim he has been robbed of the payroll. They will go 50-50 but it is clear Otto intends to kill Eddie and take off with it all. Eddie refuses backed up by Eve who has now fallen in love with Eddie.

The Rotten Tomatoes [movie info](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/air_eagles):

> In this romantic drama, two carnival barnstormers vie for the affection of a lovely woman. Their rivalry has deeper roots, as they were mortal enemies when they were WWI fighter pilots. To get the American once and for all, the German pilot tries to frame his rival's little brother.

Full movie:

At least, Bill dies at the end. I'm not sure about Otto, I didn't watch the whole movie.

There's really not much to find about it, which may explain why Pendo got its name wrong. Released at the end of 1931 - even Rotten Tomatoes believes it's from 1932.